# Getting main method issue but main method is there?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, program-entry-point

So I have a program where it is saying that I need to add public static void mean to my case but it is already in the case so I'm not sure why I am unable to get any results. My code is showing no errors but once I run I get the same message. I have two public classes so I'm adding both so anyone can see the full programming. I have absolutely no idea how to get rid of this error.

> Error: Main method not found in class finalproject, please define the
> main method as:    public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX
> application class must extend javafx.application.Application

```
public class finalproject {
    public static class employeeCase {
        //This main method doesn't work
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main is defined in `employeeCase`, not in `finalproject`. Fix that.

Comment: how so? when I move it I get an error

Comment: then fix that error. A `main` needs to be in a toplevel class.

Comment: You need to post a [mre] if you want help.  I shouldn't be reading code about employees and final projects.  If your question is about a main method in a nested class, then you need to post a program that **only** has a main method in a nested class.  Please read [ask].

Comment: I posted the entire thing because my coding looks good but the static void main issue is the only thing I need help with

Comment: You should  not have removed your code after you got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is stating that you need a `main` method in the `finalproject` class. Once you have added that method then you can call any other method you want, which in your case would be `employeeCase.main(args);`:

```
public class finalproject {

    //Add the below three lines:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        employeeCase.main(args);
    }

    public static class employeeCase {
        ....
```